# Customize UITabBar control

Tags: iphone

Any one know how to customize the UITabBar control?

I want to make it scrollable, Don't want to use "more" tab.

Comment: What kind of customization do you want to do ?

Comment: you cant customize the default tab bar.. you'll have to create a new one urself.. if you do, don't forget to share it... many people on SO keep looking for custom tab bar controllers...

Answer (score 2):

if you want scrollable tabbar view, you have to do it as your own.you can add multiple buttons in scrollview, u have to handle viewcontroller for eachbutton.that scollable buttons will be in UIWindow.

Comment: Thanks for given the ans. I know this method very well, but i want to customize UITabBar same like customize UILabel, Cell of UITableView.

Comment: you can customize UIButton as u customize UILabel, Cell of UITableView.and then you can use in scrollivew..i could not understand what is you need?

Comment: I want to customize UITabBar control.

Comment: You can't customize Apple's UITabBar control to make it scrollable, you have to make one from scratch based on a UIScrollView. What you are asking is not possible.